# The window's fullscreen is working, but not properly. Why?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I am trying customtkinter to make an app. i want the app to be fullscreen and cover the whole screen.

Here are the codes:

```
import customtkinter as ctk
class Window(ctk.CTk):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.wm_attributes("-fullscreen", True)
    self.resizable(False, False)
    self.toplevel_window = None
    #(some codes)

w = Window()
w.mainloop()
```

The result is something like this:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJdaU.png)
It seems to be fullscreen, but it does not cover the entire screen.

I have also tried `self.state("zoomed")` which does nothing and `self.attributes("-fullscreen", True)` which gives the same result.

Comment: The code you provided starts in fullscreen. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem a while ago. This worked for me:

```
window_name.state('zoomed')
```

instead of

```
self.wm_attributes("-fullscreen", True)
```

ps: I think you are probably a beginner because you are using tkinter. Its completely fine if you want to test your skills with app development, but i would encourage you to learn something different if you want to develop apps :)

Comment: You can make good looking apps with `tkinter` like [this](https://github.com/TheLizzard/Bismuth-184/blob/main/screenshot.png) but it's hard. `tkinter` has most of the basics that you would ever need. From those basics you can do quite a lot (but it takes quite a bit of code).